# loop through df, grep, then split

Tags: r, reshape2

I want to loop through several dataframes, and certain columns within each dataframe, and separate columns with numbers in brackets with asterisks into two columns. For instance, splitting [123]*** into a column with 123 (no brackets) and column with ***. Here's what I've tried:

```
require(reshape2)
# create dataframes
  df1 <- data.frame(var=c("item1", "item2"),
                    var.se.1=c("[123]**", "[456]"),
                    var.se.2=c("[1]***", "[45]*"))
  df2 <- data.frame(var=c("item3", "item4"),
                    var.se.1=c("[7]*", "[89]***"),
                    var.se.2=c("[34]**", "[2]"))
```

I have:

```
# df1
#     var var.se.1 var.se.2
# 1 item1  [123]**   [1]***
# 2 item2    [456]    [45]*
```

I want:

```
#     var var.se.1 var.se.1.ast var.se.2 var.se.2.ast
# 1 item1      123           **        1          ***
# 2 item2      456                    45            *
```

I tried:

```
# create list of dataframes
  dfs <- list(df1, df2)
# loop through dataframes
  for (i in 1:length(dfs)) {
    # index columns with .se in the name
      seCols <- grep(".se", names(dfs[[i]]))
    # loop through every column with .se in the name
      for (s in seCols) {
        # remove [, which will leave ] to split on
        # want to get rid of [] anyway
          dfs[[i]][,s] <- gsub("\\[", "", as.character(dfs[[i]][,s]))
        # split into two columns on ]
          dfs[[i]] <- cbind(dfs[[i]],
                            colsplit(dfs[[i]][,s],
                                     pattern = "\\]",
                                     names = c(names(dfs[[i]][s]),
                                               paste(names(dfs[[i]][s]),
                                                     "ast", sep="."))))
      }
  }
```

The code is mostly doing what I want it to do, but the results are not being stored in the dataframe. If I run the loop and then run `dfs[[i]]`, so when `i==2`, I get the following:

```
# i == 2
dfs[[i]]
    var var.se.1 var.se.2 var.se.1 var.se.1.ast var.se.2 var.se.2.ast
1 item3      7]*    34]**        7            *       34           **
2 item4   89]***       2]       89          ***        2
```

I need to delete columns 2 and 3, but other than that, it works. Just need to get columns 1, 4, 5, 6, and 7 (column naming is correct) into `df1` and `df2` (`df2` in this case).

**UPDATE**

My actual use case is more complex than the MRE and breaks @Tyler's code. The problem seems to be related to my real dataframes having different numbers of observations. If we redefine `df2` to have 3 rows, and leave `df2` to have 2 rows, R will throw an error when running @Tyler's code: "Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 2, 3"

```
df2 <- data.frame(var=c("item3", "item4", "item5"),
                  var.se.1=c("[7]*", "[89]***", "new"),
                  var.se.2=c("[34]**", "[2]", "rows"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one approach using the qdap package.  I made some tweaks based on the OP's comments.  I'd operate out of the list but if you wanted them to be in the global environment I provide that as well.

```
L1 <- setNames(list(df1, df2), c("df1", "df2"))

library(qdap)

bot_scum <- function(x) identical(character(0), x)
FUN <- function(x) {
    y <- bracketXtract(x)
    y[sapply(y, bot_scum)] <- NA
    as.numeric(unlist(y))
}
FUN2 <- function(x) gsub("[^*]", "", x)
FUN3 <- function(x) cbind.data.frame(FUN(x), FUN2(x))

(L2 <- lapply(L1, function(x) {
    inds <- grep(".se", colnames(x), fixed=TRUE)
    ninds <- grep(".se", colnames(x), fixed=TRUE, invert=TRUE)

    out <- do.call(cbind.data.frame, lapply(inds, function(i) {
        setNames(FUN3(x[, i]), c(colnames(x)[i], paste0(colnames(x)[i], ".ast")))
    }))

    cbind.data.frame(x[, ninds, drop=FALSE],out)
}))

list2env(L2, envir = .GlobalEnv)
df1
df2

## $df1
##     var var.se.1 var.se.1.ast var.se.2 var.se.2.ast
## 1 item1      123           **        1          ***
## 2 item2      456                    45            *
## 
## $df2
##     var var.se.1 var.se.1.ast var.se.2 var.se.2.ast
## 1 item3        7            *       34           **
## 2 item4       89          ***        2
```

Comment: Interesting approach, @Tyler. How would I put the results into `df1` and `df2`?

Comment: See my edits.  But working out of a list is the cool thing to do these days, at least compared to multiple frames in the global env.  `dplyr` and `data.table` may be cooler than working from a list though, I'm not that cool so I can't tell you.

Comment: I was using loops, so you can judge my cool factor. `list2env` is very cool. Did not know about this or your package `qdap`. Looks like the second asterisk column gets named 2.1 rather than 2.ast. Thoughts about how to change? Also, it looks like the answer, which is great, is hard coded to the MRE. In my actual use case, the dataframes vary in length. The only constant is that the columns I want to split have `.se` in the name.

Comment: Per your comments to BRodieG I have made it more flexible for when you don't know column order just `.se`.  A lot more code than when we started though.

Comment: wrapping my head around the apply. In my actual case, the dataframes have different numbers of rows. I wonder if this is causing the script to break. It seems to choke on `cbind.data.frame(x[, ninds, drop=FALSE],out)`. "Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 33, 0". Still troubleshooting.

Comment: The problem does seem to be related to rows. When I add a new row to my toy example, it breaks with the error I referenced in my previous comment. I'll edit my question to show this.

Comment: This is gotten to be awful messy, with this info it's probably be wise to scrap this and start with a new approach.  It should work.  Lesson: Make sure to think about corner cases when describing the problem.  The original question was well written and provided desired output, if you get the corner case thinking in there you'll have stellar questions.

Comment: that's good advice. I should have looked at my use case and realized that dimension variation across dataframes was probably important to capture in my MRE. Thanks for the revised solution. For some reason, I'm getting an error: "Error in match.fun(FUN) : object 'bot_scum' not found". I'm starting with a clean workspace, creating `df1` and `df2` as specified above (2 rows, 3 rows), and running your new code.

Comment: Excellent, @Tyler. Thanks a lot. In case anyone else tries to implement, I should note that one of my real tables does not have any columns with []**, so I remove it from `L1`. Works perfectly on MRE with df's of varying dimensions.

Comment: UPDATE: @Tyler informed me that `qdapRegex` is lighter weight than its parent package `qdap`, and is now recommended.

Answer (score 2):

Not as clean as Tyler's was, but in base:

```
lapply(
  dfs,
  function(df) {
    proc.cols <- lapply(df[grep("se.", names(df), fixed=TRUE)], 
      function(df.col) {
        df.col.chr <- as.character(df.col)
        matched.vals <- vapply(
          regmatches(df.col.chr, regexec("\\[([0-9]+)\\](\\**)", df.col.chr)),
          `[`, character(2L), -1L
        )
        t(matched.vals)
    } )
    do.call(cbind, c(list(df[!grepl("se.", names(df), fixed=TRUE)]), proc.cols))
} )
```

Produces:

```
[[1]]
    var var.se.1.1 var.se.1.2 var.se.2.1 var.se.2.2
1 item1        123         **          1        ***
2 item2        456                    45          *

[[2]]
    var var.se.1.1 var.se.1.2 var.se.2.1 var.se.2.2
1 item3          7          *         34         **
2 item4         89        ***          2
```

Basically we loop through the list, then loop through all but the first column of each data frame, and use regmatches to pull out he numbers and the stars.

Comment: Thanks, @BrodieG. I like the base approach, however I need to grep on `.se` in the column name because my actual use case is larger and more complex. I'm looking for a solution that follows my naming scheme.

Comment: In other words, I have to select specific columns based on grep rather than assume all but first column.

Comment: @EricGreen, see slight modification that will do what you want.  Only issues is that se columns will be last and all others first, so if you had others interspersed with the se columns the order will be lost.

Comment: Your regex is not giving the correct result - you always end up with just one `*`

Comment: Dumb question for you @BrodieG: I get the same output, but how do I store the results? I tried @Tyler's `list2env`, but it doesn't work because your code is not altering the list contents (at least I don't think it is). Also, do you see an easy way to get my naming scheme: `var var.se.1 var.se.1.ast var.se.2 var.se.2.ast`?

Comment: @EricGreen, to store the results in a list just add `my.list <- lappy(...` at the beginning (the `lapply` bit is obviously already in the code above).  You can then access each data frame with `my.list[[1]]`, etc.  For the names you can just use `sub` on the names of the result of `do.call(cbind...)` (i.e. store that, then do something like `names(xxx) <- sub("([0-9]+)\\.1", "\\1", names(xxx)` to get rid of `.1`, and  sub("([0-9]+)\\.2", "\\1.ast", names(xxx)`, to replace the `.2` with `ast`.  Read `?names` and `?sub` for details.